# Instagram api get public tag photo in live mode?

Tags: api, tags, instagram, live, public

I would like to get the photos for a given tag, however `Instagram` said that it was not possible for `Sandbox` applications.
So I have tried to go to live mode, however on submission it is said

> This use case is not supported. We do not approve the public_content
>   permission for one-off projects such as displaying hashtag based
>   content on your website. As alternative solution, you can show your
>   own Instagram content, or find a company that offers this type of
>   service (content discover, moderation, and display).

Does this mean that is not possible at all ?

Will it be possible if I chose the option

> *My product helps brands and advertisers understand, manage their audience and media rights*

on submitting ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue trying to get data from Instagram API. It seems that since you are in Sandbox mode, you'll have to go through a process to actually get any useful data. So, I was able to get tags and the amount of posts in those tags as well as similar tags. The solution I found on Stack Overflow and am currently working on to make better for my needs is written below. I am using Python requests, BeautifulSoup and JSON to get the data and then I go through the data to get the images.

```
import sys, os, json, requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pprint import pprint  

base_url = "https://instagram.com/explore/tags/"
url = str(base_url + <tag>)
res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")
script_tag = soup.find("script", text=re.compile("window\._sharedData"))
shared_data = script_tag.string.partition("=")[-1].strip(" ;")
result = json.loads(shared_data)
tag_page = result["entry_data"]["TagPage"][0]["tag"]
media = tag_page["media"]["nodes"]
pprint(media)
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for this information ! I'll try to make an API to get the data from  https://instagram.com/explore/tags/ 
In fact I didn't knew that such page exists...

Comment: No problem! Actually, after I wrote this I did a bit more research and found a differentiation between getting most recent posts per tag and top posts per tag. Here's what I found: tag_page_top = result['entry_data']['TagPage'][0]['tag']['top_posts']['nodes'] for top posts and tag_page_recent = result['entry_data']['TagPage'][0]['tag']['media']['nodes'] for the most recent posts per tag.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about this difference. it will avoid loss of time.